# How to display the accurate Current Location in Google Map android

Tags: android

Hi Guys iam writing a Google Maps application to display current location every time i enters into an Activity.For this i have used the below code.

public class MapViewCompassDemo extends MapActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "MapViewCompassDemo";
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private RotateView mRotateView;
private MapView mMapView;
private MyLocationOverlay mMyLocationOverlay;

private class RotateView extends ViewGroup implements SensorListener {
    private static final float SQ2 = 1.414213562373095f;
    private final SmoothCanvas mCanvas = new SmoothCanvas();
    private float mHeading = 0;

    public RotateView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "x: " + values[0] + "y: " + values[1] + "z: " + values[2]);
        synchronized (this) {
            mHeading = values[0];
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.rotate(-mHeading, getWidth() * 0.5f, getHeight() * 0.5f);
        mCanvas.delegate = canvas;
        super.dispatchDraw(mCanvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        final int width = getWidth();
        final int height = getHeight();
        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View view = getChildAt(i);
            final int childWidth = view.getMeasuredWidth();
            final int childHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
            final int childLeft = (width - childWidth) / 2;
            final int childTop = (height - childHeight) / 2;
            view.layout(childLeft, childTop, childLeft + childWidth, childTop + childHeight);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int w = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        int h = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        int sizeSpec;
        if (w > h) {
            sizeSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int) (w * SQ2), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        } else {
            sizeSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int) (h * SQ2), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }
        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            getChildAt(i).measure(sizeSpec, sizeSpec);
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // TODO: rotate events too
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(int sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mRotateView = new RotateView(this);
    mMapView = new MapView(this, "MapViewCompassDemo_DummyAPIKey");
    mRotateView.addView(mMapView);
    setContentView(mRotateView);

    mMyLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mMapView);
    mMyLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() { public void run() {
        mMapView.getController().animateTo(mMyLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
    }});
    mMapView.getOverlays().add(mMyLocationOverlay);
    mMapView.getController().setZoom(18);
    mMapView.setClickable(true);
    mMapView.setEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mRotateView,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    mMyLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mRotateView);
    mMyLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}


static final class SmoothCanvas extends Canvas {
    Canvas delegate;

    private final Paint mSmooth = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        delegate.setBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    public void setViewport(int width, int height) {
        delegate.setViewport(width, height);
    }

    public boolean isOpaque() {
        return delegate.isOpaque();
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return delegate.getWidth();
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return delegate.getHeight();
    }

    public int save() {
        return delegate.save();
    }

    public int save(int saveFlags) {
        return delegate.save(saveFlags);
    }

    public int saveLayer(RectF bounds, Paint paint, int saveFlags) {
        return delegate.saveLayer(bounds, paint, saveFlags);
    }

    public int saveLayer(float left, float top, float right, float
            bottom, Paint paint,
            int saveFlags) {
        return delegate.saveLayer(left, top, right, bottom, paint,
                saveFlags);
    }

    public int saveLayerAlpha(RectF bounds, int alpha, int saveFlags) {
        return delegate.saveLayerAlpha(bounds, alpha, saveFlags);
    }

    public int saveLayerAlpha(float left, float top, float right,
            float bottom, int alpha,
            int saveFlags) {
        return delegate.saveLayerAlpha(left, top, right, bottom,
                alpha, saveFlags);
    }

    public void restore() {
        delegate.restore();
    }

    public int getSaveCount() {
        return delegate.getSaveCount();
    }

    public void restoreToCount(int saveCount) {
        delegate.restoreToCount(saveCount);
    }

    public void translate(float dx, float dy) {
        delegate.translate(dx, dy);
    }

    public void scale(float sx, float sy) {
        delegate.scale(sx, sy);
    }

    public void rotate(float degrees) {
        delegate.rotate(degrees);
    }

    public void skew(float sx, float sy) {
        delegate.skew(sx, sy);
    }

    public void concat(Matrix matrix) {
        delegate.concat(matrix);
    }

    public void setMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
        delegate.setMatrix(matrix);
    }

    public void getMatrix(Matrix ctm) {
        delegate.getMatrix(ctm);
    }

    public boolean clipRect(RectF rect, Region.Op op) {
        return delegate.clipRect(rect, op);
    }

    public boolean clipRect(Rect rect, Region.Op op) {
        return delegate.clipRect(rect, op);
    }

    public boolean clipRect(RectF rect) {
        return delegate.clipRect(rect);
    }

    public boolean clipRect(Rect rect) {
        return delegate.clipRect(rect);
    }

    public boolean clipRect(float left, float top, float right,
            float bottom, Region.Op op) {
        return delegate.clipRect(left, top, right, bottom, op);
    }

    public boolean clipRect(float left, float top, float right,
            float bottom) {
        return delegate.clipRect(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    public boolean clipRect(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        return delegate.clipRect(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    public boolean clipPath(Path path, Region.Op op) {
        return delegate.clipPath(path, op);
    }

    public boolean clipPath(Path path) {
        return delegate.clipPath(path);
    }

    public boolean clipRegion(Region region, Region.Op op) {
        return delegate.clipRegion(region, op);
    }

    public boolean clipRegion(Region region) {
        return delegate.clipRegion(region);
    }

    public DrawFilter getDrawFilter() {
        return delegate.getDrawFilter();
    }

    public void setDrawFilter(DrawFilter filter) {
        delegate.setDrawFilter(filter);
    }

    public GL getGL() {
        return delegate.getGL();
    }

    public boolean quickReject(RectF rect, EdgeType type) {
        return delegate.quickReject(rect, type);
    }

    public boolean quickReject(Path path, EdgeType type) {
        return delegate.quickReject(path, type);
    }

    public boolean quickReject(float left, float top, float right,
            float bottom,
            EdgeType type) {
        return delegate.quickReject(left, top, right, bottom, type);
    }

    public boolean getClipBounds(Rect bounds) {
        return delegate.getClipBounds(bounds);
    }

    public void drawRGB(int r, int g, int b) {
        delegate.drawRGB(r, g, b);
    }

    public void drawARGB(int a, int r, int g, int b) {
        delegate.drawARGB(a, r, g, b);
    }

    public void drawColor(int color) {
        delegate.drawColor(color);
    }

    public void drawColor(int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode) {
        delegate.drawColor(color, mode);
    }

    public void drawPaint(Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawPaint(paint);
    }

    public void drawPoints(float[] pts, int offset, int count,
            Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawPoints(pts, offset, count, paint);
    }

    public void drawPoints(float[] pts, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawPoints(pts, paint);
    }

    public void drawPoint(float x, float y, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawPoint(x, y, paint);
    }

    public void drawLine(float startX, float startY, float stopX,
            float stopY, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, paint);
    }

    public void drawLines(float[] pts, int offset, int count, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawLines(pts, offset, count, paint);
    }

    public void drawLines(float[] pts, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawLines(pts, paint);
    }

    public void drawRect(RectF rect, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawRect(rect, paint);
    }

    public void drawRect(Rect r, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawRect(r, paint);
    }

    public void drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float
            bottom, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
    }

    public void drawOval(RectF oval, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawOval(oval, paint);
    }

    public void drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float radius, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint);
    }

    public void drawArc(RectF oval, float startAngle, float
            sweepAngle, boolean useCenter,
            Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawArc(oval, startAngle, sweepAngle, useCenter, paint);
    }

    public void drawRoundRect(RectF rect, float rx, float ry, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawRoundRect(rect, rx, ry, paint);
    }

    public void drawPath(Path path, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    public void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top,
            Paint paint) {
        if (paint == null) {
            paint = mSmooth;
        } else {
            paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        }
        delegate.drawBitmap(bitmap, left, top, paint);
    }

    public void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst,
            Paint paint) {
        if (paint == null) {
            paint = mSmooth;
        } else {
            paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        }
        delegate.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, paint);
    }

    public void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint) {
        if (paint == null) {
            paint = mSmooth;
        } else {
            paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        }
        delegate.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, paint);
    }

    public void drawBitmap(int[] colors, int offset, int stride,
            int x, int y, int width,
            int height, boolean hasAlpha, Paint paint) {
        if (paint == null) {
            paint = mSmooth;
        } else {
            paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        }
        delegate.drawBitmap(colors, offset, stride, x, y, width,
                height, hasAlpha, paint);
    }

    public void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix, Paint paint) {
        if (paint == null) {
            paint = mSmooth;
        } else {
            paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        }
        delegate.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
    }

    public void drawBitmapMesh(Bitmap bitmap, int meshWidth, int
            meshHeight, float[] verts,
            int vertOffset, int[] colors, int colorOffset, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawBitmapMesh(bitmap, meshWidth, meshHeight,
                verts, vertOffset, colors,
                colorOffset, paint);
    }

    public void drawVertices(VertexMode mode, int vertexCount,
            float[] verts, int vertOffset,
            float[] texs, int texOffset, int[] colors, int
            colorOffset, short[] indices,
            int indexOffset, int indexCount, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawVertices(mode, vertexCount, verts,
                vertOffset, texs, texOffset, colors,
                colorOffset, indices, indexOffset, indexCount, paint);
    }

    public void drawText(char[] text, int index, int count, float
            x, float y, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawText(text, index, count, x, y, paint);
    }

    public void drawText(String text, float x, float y, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
    }

    public void drawText(String text, int start, int end, float x,
            float y, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);
    }

    public void drawText(CharSequence text, int start, int end,
            float x, float y, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawText(text, start, end, x, y, paint);
    }

    public void drawPosText(char[] text, int index, int count,
            float[] pos, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawPosText(text, index, count, pos, paint);
    }

    public void drawPosText(String text, float[] pos, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawPosText(text, pos, paint);
    }

    public void drawTextOnPath(char[] text, int index, int count,
            Path path, float hOffset,
            float vOffset, Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawTextOnPath(text, index, count, path, hOffset,
                vOffset, paint);
    }

    public void drawTextOnPath(String text, Path path, float
            hOffset, float vOffset,
            Paint paint) {
        delegate.drawTextOnPath(text, path, hOffset, vOffset, paint);
    }

    public void drawPicture(Picture picture) {
        delegate.drawPicture(picture);
    }

    public void drawPicture(Picture picture, RectF dst) {
        delegate.drawPicture(picture, dst);
    }

    public void drawPicture(Picture picture, Rect dst) {
        delegate.drawPicture(picture, dst);
    }
}
```

}

So whenever i enters into this Activity for the First time iam able to see the current location correctly.But whenever i enter into this activiy for the next time with changed location iam seeing the the marker in the previous location then after some time it is moving to the current location.Here i need to display the current location immediately.Any idea about this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait for the phone to triangulate the location either from the GSM or the GPS signal. You could hide the main view and monitor the MyLocationOverlay. Once you can make sure that the location comes from the GPS (GSM or coarse is not good enough but it's quicker) you can show the view again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your code how you configured LocationManager, but obviously it returns  getLastKnownLocation(). For the first time lastKnownLocation is null, that's why it will wait some time until LocationListener get a location, next times lastKnownLocation will be shown as a current location right away and after some delay when LocationListener get a new location it will render an overlay in a new place.